# Function takes a string and returns an object of the letters and number of occurrences -javascript - Homework Warning

Tags: javascript, object

Im working with this challenge question and I am struggling with the number count. I can get it work to return the position in the string, but not the actual letter count.  Any help is appreciated.

Question -

Write a function named letterCount that takes a string and returns an
object with the letters and the number of their occurrences.

My Code so far -

```
var stringCount = "Hello";

function letterCount(string) {
   var stringObject = {};
   for (var i = 0; i < string.length; i++) {
     stringObject[string[i]] = [i];
   }

   return stringObject;
}

letterCount(stringCount);
```

Comment: Please learn [ask]. Give a [mcve] with a clear, specific error.

Comment: @jonrsharpe That's a [mcve]. What happened to you?

Comment: @praveen when you see help vampires, please do try not to bare your next and bend over

Comment: @jonrsharpe I know... This looks like a legit mistake. Who does something like that! `:o`

Comment: thanks didnt know - went thru and did that.  I appreciate your help

Comment: @EKR You are welcome buddy. `:D`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have done almost everything right, only problem is the assignment part, which you need to do this way:

```js
var stringCount = "Hello";

function letterCount(string) {
  var stringObject = {};
  for (var i = 0; i < string.length; i++) {
    stringObject[string[i]] = ((stringObject[string[i]]) ? stringObject[string[i]] : 0) + 1;
  }
  return stringObject;
}

console.log(letterCount(stringCount));
```

So technically, what happens in the line:

```
stringObject[string[i]] = ((stringObject[string[i]]) ? stringObject[string[i]] : 0) + 1;
```

- The program checks if that particular index exists in the object.
- If it doesn't exists (not defined, `undefined`), it assigns `0`.
- If it exists, it takes the same value.
- It adds `1` to the above value.

The same above line can be written this way:

```
// Check if the current key exists.
if (typeof stringObject[string[i]] == "undefined") {
  // If it doesn't, initialise it 1.
  stringObject[string[i]] = 1;
} else {
  // If it exists, increment it.
  stringObject[string[i]] = stringObject[string[i]] + 1;
  // Another way:
  // stringObject[string[i]]++;
}
```

Comment: Or of course, `stringObject[string[i]] = (stringObject[string[i]] || 0) + 1;`, but maybe not something to throw at a newbie...

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Yes, that's why I gave a full explanation. Can I make the code for the newbie simpler?